# Flutter Provider.of<MyProvider>(...) returns null

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have a problem with `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider`.

I have a list of providers like

```
 providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Auth(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, MyProvider>(
            create: (context) => MyProvider(),
            update: (ctx, auth, myProvider) => myProvider.update(auth)),
      ],
```

If I call `Provider.of<MyProvider>(context, listen: false);` or `context.read<MyProvider>();` in my classes I got a null object.

In another case, if I replace `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider` to `ChangeNotifierProvider` (without proxy), I got my provider object.

I didn't find any similar questions. So I guess I miss something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is:

```dart
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, MyProvider>(
   create: (context) => MyProvider(),
  update: (ctx, auth, myProvider) {
    myProvider.update(auth);
    return myProvider;
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it's working.
The article on pub.dev is not very clear... I can't find that I need to return provider in the update method.